# i need to resize image in tensorflow

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, resize, classification

I have 50000 images in 32x32x3 and want to reshape them to 299x299x3. I want to resize them in batches and store them on a disc.
to resize in batches I am using this function. but doesn't work.

```
def latent_func(images):
    ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    for i in tf.range(len(images):
         resize=tf.image.resize(images[i], [299,299])
         ta = ta.write(i,resize ) 
     
         
        
    return ta.stack()
```

Comment: Ha, what exactly does not work? Be specific

Comment: when i give the entire training images which is 50,000 images the kernel dies due to memory issue. That's the reason I want to resize them in batches ,store them in drive and stack them to feed to my model. I was successful in resizing one batch of  500 images by just passing train_image[:500] as argument of the function. But I can't do it for images after that or I don't know how to code rightly and saving them. I tried changing the range to tf.range(500,1000) and argument of function to [500:1000] but doesn't work. This method gives tensor of shape [0,299,299,3].